# How do I loop through similar key value pairs(a0,a1,a2) in JavaScript object and generate a new array without the number in the key(a)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

What I have
1.keys:  similar key name(such as a0,a1,a2)
2.obj: a lot of similar key-value pairs in one object
3.number:  the times similar key-value pairs looped in obj1)
4.arr: a array without the number in the key(only keep "a", no "a0","a1","a2")

p.s. "aa","bb","cc" are examples, the value can be anything

```
let keys = ["javascript","java","python","php"];
let number = 3;
let obj = {
javascript0:"a",java0:"b",python0:"c",php0:"d",
javascript1:"aa",java1:"bb",python1:"cc",php1:"dd",
javascript2:"aaa",java2:"bbb",python2:"ccc",php2:"ddd",
}
```

What I want

```
let arr = [
{javascript:"a",java:"b",python:"c",php:"d"},
{javascript:"aa",java:"bb",python:"cc",php:"dd"},
{javascript:"aaa",java:"bbb",python:"ccc",php:"ddd"}
]
```

How can I get array?

Comment: You'll need to specify what qualifies as similar. Put the rules for what should happen into words, then turn the words into code

Comment: A tomato is technically a fruit...

Comment: Please show what research you've done, and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: To emphasise the importance of @HereticMonkey. By showing what you've already tried it: shows to us you've actually tried to solve this yourself, helps us understand exactly what you are trying to do, and helps us find the best way to answer to help you the most :) Check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let keys = ["javascript", "java", "python", "php"];

let obj = {
  javascript0: "a0",
  java0: "b0",
  python0: "c0",
  php0: "d0",
  javascript1: "a1",
  java1: "b1",
  python1: "c1",
  php1: "d1",
  javascript2: "a2",
  java2: "b2",
  python2: "c2",
  php2: "d2",
};

let result = [];
let number = 3;
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  let _r = {};
  keys.forEach((item) => {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(`${item}${i}`)) {
      _r[item] = obj[`${item}${i}`];
    }
  });
  result.push(_r);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. In a *functional programming* way, it could be done with `Array.from` and `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
let keys = ["javascript","java","python","php"];
let number = 3;
let obj1 = {
    javascript0:"a0",java0:"b0",python0:"c0",php0:"d0",
    javascript1:"a1",java1:"b1",python1:"c1",php1:"d1",
    javascript2:"a2",java2:"b2",python2:"c2",php2:"d2",
}

let arr = Array.from({length: number}, (_, i) =>
    Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, obj1[key + i]]))
);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer very much. Some people said my question was not very clear so I made it more simple. unfortunately, you code doesn't work but thank you to give me the thought of using "fromEntries" and "entries". I will try to use them. @trincot

Comment: Oh, I see you changed the desired output in your question... Now you just want the array? What do you mean with "doesn't work". The snippet runs without error here and provides the output you had specified in your question at the time I answered. Anyway, I updated my answer to bring it in line again with your question.

Comment: I said it doesn't work because in the array, the keys still are "javascript0, java0, python0, php0; javascript1, java1, python1, php1......", what I want is "javascript, java, python, php" no number in the keys. Therefore, it still doesn't work after you change the answer. But thank you answer my question again. @trincot

Comment: Oh I see. Just removed that suffix.